# Bitcoin wallet address

Tags: bitcoin-core, paper-wallet

I generated a paper wallet. Then search Blockchain.com with the public key. There are 2 blockchain results with same public key. 1) BTC address and 2) BCH address. This is confusing. How can I generate a public key that is only for BTC address?

Comment: Just ignore the BCH address. Nothing else is needed

Comment: Noted, tks MCCCS